# Using pandas apply to pass in both a row and the entire dataframe with it

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df and I want to create some new cols with it. How would I use the apply function to both pass in the row, and the entire df with it? I need the entire df to do some filtering, and the data is subject to the values in each row.

Or maybe I don't need to use apply, but that's the first thing that came to my mind. Thank you and all help is appreciated!

Ex of df:

```
+----+--------+--------+
| ID | Family | Amount |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 | A      |      2 |
|  2 | A      |     10 |
|  3 | B      |      4 |
|  4 | B      |      7 |
+----+--------+--------+
```

Result:

```
+----+--------+--------+-----------+------------+
| ID | Family | Amount | Total_Fam | Id_Percent |
+----+--------+--------+-----------+------------+
|  1 | A      |      2 |        12 |       .166 |
|  2 | A      |     10 |        12 |       .833 |
|  3 | B      |      4 |        11 |       .363 |
|  4 | B      |      7 |        11 |       .636 |
+----+--------+--------+-----------+------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, group by `Family` and then transform amount and then you can directly divide `Amount` by the new column.

```
df['Total_Fam'] = df.groupby('Family')['Amount'].transform(np.sum)
df['Id_Percent'] = df['Amount']/df['Total_Fam']
df
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, quick question, what if i have way more cols i care about, for example I also have to match other items such as dates and stuff. Can I just continue to add items to the groupby statement?

Comment: @mike_gundy123, is your question adding more items to grouper or the columns you have to transform/apply?

Comment: Nvm I figured it out. I meant for adding more items to the grouper.

Answer (score 0):

Using `apply` on a column passes each row individualy. If you use `apply` on the entire dataset, it sees the entire dataset, hence, you can use all columns. As you can see in the example below, `df['new_2]` which is made using a function which I apply to the dataset, I do not need to pass the `df` to it.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('iris')

df['new'] = df['species'].apply(lambda x: x[:2])

def sumIsMore(dataframe):
    x = dataframe['sepal_length']
    y = dataframe['sepal_width']

    return x+y >= 8.5

df['new_2'] = df.apply(sumIsMore, axis=1)
```